# Execute method delayed and only once even if triggered twice within the delay

Tags: c#

I have the case, that I have two properties which both have change notification via `INotifyPropertyChanged` and trigger a reconfiguration of my attached hardware, which takes some time and can't be executed twice in parallel.

Now there is one situation where both of these properties are changed "at the same time" and would trigger two reconfigurations after another.

To avoid that I would like to implement some kind of a delay before executing the reconfiguration and "ignore" the second call if one is already pending.

Is there some common pattern or logic available to solve something like this?
At the moment I use something like the following:

```
public class ExecutionManager
{
    private readonly object reconfigurationLock = new object();
    private bool reconfigurationScheduled;

    /// <summary>Reconfigures the measurement.</summary>
    public void ReconfigureMeasurement()
    {
        //slow/long method
    }

    /// <summary>Reconfigures the measurement delayed so two calls short after each other only trigger one reconfiguration.</summary>
    public void ReconfigureMeasurementDelayed()
    {
        lock (reconfigurationLock)
        {
            if (reconfigurationScheduled)
                return;
            reconfigurationScheduled = true;
        }

        Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(50).ConfigureAwait(false);
                ReconfigureMeasurement();
                reconfigurationScheduled = false;
            });
    }
}
```

...but this seems a little bit "hacky" to me and I have the feeling there is a way better solution to my problem.

One thing which is important to keep in mind:
I can NOT call `ReconfigureMeasurement` before the second change event also "happened" as this would cause that the changed value of that one is lost, as the new values are sent to the hardware directly at the beginning of `ReconfigureMeasurement` and so before the second parameter changed if I have no delay.

Comment: Your code is a race. `ReconfigureMeasurement` can be called several  times with this code.

Comment: In your code, you reset reconfigurationScheduled before starting ReconfigureManagement, so what's the point? It can still be called multiple times.

Comment: Unrelated, but I think `reconfigurationScheduled = false;` should be after `ReconfigureMeasurement`, otherwise you're still vulnerable to the same issue

Comment: @all above: Yes, that was wrong, thanks...

Comment: Looks like a job for my favorite hammer! Rx.Net!

Comment: There are better solutions. One would be a some kind of transaction mechanism which could be used to ensure your object model was in a consistent and unchanging state while it's being read to reconfigure the hardware. Judging from the use of locks I would assume the notifications are coming from another thread - meaning things are changing underneath ReconfigureMeasurement. A recipe for disaster in my experience.

Comment: @Aron - are you thinking about [Observable.Throttle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.throttle(v=vs.103).aspx), perchance?

Comment: @jaket: The properties are in the view-model and are bound to input controls in the UI. And there is one special case, where a third property in the VM triggers a change in both other properties.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever A second reading of the OP makes me agree that `Observable.Throttle` whilst not being to spec, is a much better UX than the OP gives, since it doesn't give the arse backwards problem of having the UI state and the program state completely out of sync.

Comment: @Aron: Can you post that as an answer? I solved it using `Observable.Throttle` thanks to your suggestion - I will add my solution for reference...

Comment: @ChrFin I suggest you post your own code up as an answer then mark it as accepted. My comment was merely that, a comment. You formed it into an answer.

Comment: @Aron Done - thanks again for pushing me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I use the following solution thanks to Arons comment:

```
public class ExecutionManager
{
    private readonly int reconfigurationDelay = 50;
    private IObservable<EventArgs> delayedReconfigurations;

    /// <summary>Occurs when a reconfiguration is required.</summary>
    public event EventHandler ReconfigurationRequired;
    /// <summary>Called when a reconfiguration is required.</summary>
    public void OnReconfigurationRequired() => ReconfigurationRequired.Raise(this);

    /// <summary>Initializes the manager.</summary>
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();

        delayedReconfigurations = Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
            h => (s, e) => h(e),
            h => ReconfigurationRequired += h,
            h => ReconfigurationRequired -= h);
        delayedReconfigurations.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(reconfigurationDelay))
            .Subscribe(e => ReconfigureMeasurement());
    }

    /// <summary>Reconfigures the measurement.</summary>
    public void ReconfigureMeasurement()
    {
        //long/slow method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do:

```
    /// <summary>Reconfigures the measurement delayed so two calls short after each other only trigger one reconfiguration.</summary>
public void ReconfigureMeasurementDelayed()
{
    lock (reconfigurationLock)
    {
        if (reconfigurationScheduled)
            return;
        reconfigurationScheduled = true;
    }

    Task.Run(() =>
        {                                
            ReconfigureMeasurement();
            lock (reconfigurationLock) {
                 reconfigurationScheduled = false;
            }
        });
}
```

And no need for any delays, they are not solving problem anyway.

Comment: I overlooked. This looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this would not work for me - please see my updated question (note at the end)...

Comment: @ChrFin well you didn't show where those properties are stored and how you set them. If you set them before you call ReconfigureMeasurementDelayed - just add your await Task.Delay(50).ConfigureAwait(false); before ReconfigureMeasurment() in code above. While this thread will be waiting, other threads can still update properties. But still better show how you work with those properties (how you write and read them, because there might also be concurrency issues).

Answer (score 1):

There is an inherent weakness in the `INotifyPropertyChanged` architecture in that it allows a client to observe a model in an inconsistent state. Consider the example below. Notice how a subscriber will receive a notification about the value X changing followed by a notification about the value XSquared changing. If the client was something like a UI where when X changes it goes back and looks only at X and then later when XSquared changes it goes back and looks only a XSquared then the problem doesn't manifest. But when you are dealing with a condition where you need to look at other parts of the model beyond what is immediately being notified then you run the risk of seeing an invalid state.

```
 class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public int X
     {
         get { return _x; }
         set 
         {
             _x = value;
             _xSquared = _a * _a;
             NotifyPropertyChanged("X");
             NotifyPropertyChanged("XSquared");
         }
     }

     public int XSquared { get { return _xSquared; }
 }
```

Having worked with these types of systems for a long time I have found that it is best to allow a change and any of its side effects to completely settle and then send a single notification that *something* changed. e.g.

```
 class ViewModel
 {
     public event EventHandler SomethingChanged;

     public int X
     {
         get { return _x; }
         set 
         {
             _x = value;
             _xSquared = _a * _a;
             SomethingChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
     }

     public int XSquared { get { return _xSquared; }
 }

 public class ExecutionManager
 {
     private ViewModel _viewModel;

     public void OnSomethingChanged(...)
     {
         // state is now consistent so long as everything is 
         // single threaded.
         ReconfigureHardware(_viewModel.X, _viewModel.XSquared);      
     }
 }
```

Comment: This exactly describes my case - I will check if I can work around it like you suggested, thanks. Ohterwise I'll look into `Observable.Throttle` like suggested in the comments...